# What kind of method is this in Python?

Tags: python

I was reading about instance, static, and class methods, and found the following.

This:

```py
class A:
    def a(self, num):
            print("A.a(): ", num)

    @staticmethod
    def aa(num):
            print("A.aa(): ", num)
```

works exactly as expected:

```py
>>> A.a(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'
# I understand that this happens since `a()` is an instance method

>>> A.aa(1)
A.aa():  1

>>> A().a(1)
A.a():  1
```

However, if I modify `A.a()` to remove `self` from its parameters, i.e.:

```py
class A:
    def a(num):
            print("A.a(): ", num)

    @staticmethod
    def aa(num):
            print("A.aa(): ", num)
```

this happens:

```py
>>> A.a(1)
A.a():  1
# I don't understand why this works

>>> A.aa(1)
A.aa():  1

>>> A().a(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
# I understand that this happens because the first argument
# being given to `a()` is the instance of A
```

What exactly happened here? If I don't pass `self` to the `a()` method, what kind of a method is it? Why does it work without an instance of the class?

Answer (score 1):

This is a static method. It will work, but it will not be able to access any of the other properties/methods that the class has. For example, suppose you have the following class.

```
class newClass:
b = 9
def print_b():
    print(b)
    
newClass.print_b()
```

This will throw an error, since the function can not access the variable b. Hope this helps.

Similarly, you can not do the following, because when you call a method like this, you automatically pass an instance of the class into the function. Consequently, the function will throw an error saying it expects 0 positional arguments, but you have passed one.

```
x = newClass()
x.print_b()
```

Comment: Thank you! This, along with answers to the "similar question" linked with this post, answer my question. For anyone else who's looking, the reason is that without the `self` parameter, the function is not 'bound' to the class (see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods).

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!